# Gem::LoadError when starting Rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04 yesterday and am working with Ruby/Rails for the first time in this environment, and copied the project directly from my Windows machine.  I installed rubygems, then `cd`'d to the project directory and ran `bundle install`, which worked without any errors.

When trying to start the server though (`rails s`) , the server never starts and I get an exception:

> /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find railties (>= 0) amongst [] (Gem::LoadError)
>
> from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
>
>   from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1208:in`gem'
>   from /usr/local/bin/rails:18

My Gemfile is as folows:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.6'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'devise'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```

Everything is for the most part what the generator left it as.  Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried? `bundle exec rails s`

Comment: @at2c just tried that, returns [this](http://pastie.org/private/ueh8tbnwtbvb5mc5xd3w).  That also should not be `:key`.  Not too sure why it works fine on my Windows machine.

Comment: in 10th line, `...sion_store :cookie_store, key: '_threexortwo_session'`.   'key: xxx' is hash in Ruby 1.9. But, in the log, I can see keyword of '1.8'. Which version do you use in both environment?

Comment: I'm using 1.9.3, but I noticed when checking with `rails -v` I get the same error as in the question.  I reinstalled 1.9.3 with RVM, reset the alias, checked with `rails -v` (worked), then ran `sudo gem install bundler` and `sudo bundle install` again.  After this, I tried rerunning the server, and it failed again.  Rain `rails -v` and I get the error again.

Comment: What is message  after `rails -v` at two directory? And try `which rails` at two directory. 1)Rails Application Root 2)Out of Rails Application (ex $home).

Comment: I'm apparently dumb and need sleep. 1.) I forgot to close all of my shells 2.) I should have done `ruby -v`.  I did `rvm implode` and did a reinstall of that.  Now, after doing this I did `rvm use 1.9.3`, checked `ruby -v` and `rails -v` -- both turned back OK.  I can't do `bundle install`, so I tried `sudo gem install bundler` (can't run as non-root), and same with `rails s` (needs sudo). Terminal log: [here](http://pastie.org/private/ayugacxghnks4mfpbradhg).  I'm not very linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got it working.  For anyone who wants the full shell log, here it is: [link](http://pastie.org/private/ujx4uh7umdwmrrwqljhw)

The issue was I believe with versions.  When using RVM, you have to set terminal to run command as a login shell.  Since for some reason everything needs to be run as sudo to work properly (I'm new to Linux), so I ran `sudo gem install rails`, then `sudo bundle install`, and now it seems to work.

Comment: This gave me the hint as to why I was getting this error. I started a new terminal, made a new rails gemset, started using the new gemset, then made a new rails application. Then I went to an OLD terminal and did "rails server" and got the error. I started a new terminal and ran "rails server" and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, this error is caused by rvm environment.

We can use particular ruby and gems in particular rails app by using rvm.

Try the following.

```
rvm gemset create [gemset_name]
cd ~/Documents/Programming/Web/threexortwo
rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p[XXX]@[gemset_name]
bundle install (not use sudo)
rails -v  (not use sudo)
rails s  (not use sudo)
```